# Get start and stop from a python slice object

Tags: python

I'm using the scipy ndimage modules and I'm using the find_objects function, which returns a slice object. Now i want to read this slice object and get the start and end indices from them. However, i can't find the way to do that.

```
fragments = ndimage.find_objects(labels)
print fragments[0][0]
> slice(0L, 832L, None)
```

How do i store the start and end indices as variables in my python code.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The members of a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) are `start`, `step` and `stop`:

> Slice objects have read-only data attributes `start`, `stop` and `step` which merely return the argument values (or their default).

---

Thus as simple as:

```
>>> sl = slice(0L, 832L)
>>> sl
slice(0L, 832L, None)
>>> start = sl.start
>>> stop = sl.stop
>>> start, stop
(0L, 832L)
```