# Get index values from slice objects in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Given a slice object 
`slice(1, 100, None)`
How can I get a a tuple / list `(1,100,None)` without parsing the string representation of the slice object. With the string representation, it's fairly obvious but is there a way to get these values from the object itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def slice_tuple(slice_):
    return slice_.start, slice_.stop, slice_.step
```

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but Google didn't turn up the duplicates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130898/get-start-and-stop-from-a-python-slice-object maybe? It doesn't specifically say about making a `tuple` out of it, but perhaps the important part is retrieving the values. I'm not sure.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That's probably a good fit.